# What type of syntax notation is this?

Tags: language-design, parsing, syntax

SQL Server documentation uses this notation, which is very easy to understand and consume. Is this a BNF Syntax Diagram? Or is this a different type of notation?

[image: Text]

Source: [SQL server documentation page with the original diagram](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: [Railroad diagram.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) [This looks like fun](https://bottlecaps.de/rr/ui), I'll have to play with it now I found it ....

Comment: It's also a stylized version of finite state machine diagraming

Comment: Is anyone aware of diagramming tools or stencils that allow these to be drawn easily by hand? The curved divergences and convergences are both aesthetically pleasing, and very useful for conveying the intended direction of flow.

Comment: @Steve - if you're willing to write your diagram in the form of a grammar, the [tool I linked above](https://bottlecaps.de/rr/ui) will do a nice job for you ...

Comment: @davidbak, indeed special tools that will generate diagrams from a grammar abound, I'm just surprised that the stylistic features of these diagrams (including the small repeater arrows which are ofren shown, though not in the example in the question) have not been incorporated into mainstream diagramming tools.

Answer (score 6):

It is a type of [syntax diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) called a railroad diagram. See also [here](https://datacadamia.com/code/compiler/railroad), [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=diagrams-how-read-railroad), and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/372019/program-for-creating-language-syntax-grammar-railroad-diagrams).

Thanks to @davidbak who found the answer.